# Javascript in Qt 5.3 Webkit QWebView is too slow, and hang the MainWindow on Windows

Tags: javascript, windows, qt, webkit

With Qt 5.3 (pre compiled installer), Win7 x64, I use Qt's QWebView to display a HTML page. The HTML will execute a javascript which will init a big variable.

slow.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function do_load() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "slow.js";
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input class="btn" type="button" onclick="do_load()" value="load">
</body>
</html>
```

slow.js:

```
if (!window.console) {
    window.console = {};
}
// union of Chrome, FF, IE, and Safari console methods
var m = [
"log", "info", "warn", "error", "debug", "trace", "dir", "group",
"groupCollapsed", "groupEnd", "time", "timeEnd", "profile", "profileEnd",
"dirxml", "assert", "count", "markTimeline", "timeStamp", "clear"
];
// define undefined methods as noops to prevent errors
for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    if (!window.console[m[i]]) {
            window.console[m[i]] = function() {};
    }    
} 

console.log("begin to init var....");
console.time("init_var");
var HSCARDS= {xxx: yyy........}  // Big variable, about 800 KBytes.
console.timeEnd("init_var");

console.log("end init var....");
```

(Complete code can be found on: https://gist.github.com/vls/24b8c70fa83b9d88830a

In Chrome 36, the variable initializing will cost about **10 ms**, and it's also very quick in IE 9 (due to lack of console.time in IE 9, no accurate time data)

But in QWebView on Windows, it will cost about **10000 ms** (Release mode, No IDE attached). And because the QWebView object is in main thread, this will **hang the MainWindow**. (On Mac with Qt 5.3, this will cost about 2000ms, **BUT** will **NOT** hang the MainWindow)

Question:

1. How to avoid javascript execution hang the MainWindow on Windows?
2. Why javascript execution in QWebView is so slow?

Comment: I am having a similar issue and would be very interested in any ideas on how to improve this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get correct speed on JavaScript, you need to compile in release with optimizations:

Add the following code to your QtCreator project (.pro)

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -Ofast
```

In my case, that solved the issue.